# Why this always runs on main thread?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I tried to implement a very simple example of `RxAndroid2`. When I try to run this code, it makes me feel confused.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(0);
    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(3);
    arr.add(4);
    arr.add(5);
    arr.add(6);

    Observable.fromIterable(arr)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                    LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            });
```

And the log always tells me that it runs on `main` thread only. 
Any idea around this? It would be very nice, if you can explain me more about observeOn() and subscribeOn().

*EDITED*: This code still gives me all main thread.

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(0);
    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(3);
    arr.add(4);
    arr.add(5);
    arr.add(6);

    Observable.fromIterable(arr)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            })
            .subscribe(integer -> {
                LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
            });
```

Comment: Very interesting question! Glad you got your answer!

Comment: Thanks for your help too! @GhostCat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the operators around:

```
Observable.fromIterable(arr)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                                                      // <------------------------
        .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        })
        .doOnNext(new Consumer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
                LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())  // <--------------------------
        .subscribe(integer -> {
            LogUtil.logD(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
```

This no longer executes the code in `doOnSubscibe` and `doOnNext` on the main thread, only the `subscribe` handler gets executed on the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

You have `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

And the [javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#observeOn(io.reactivex.Scheduler)) for `observeOn()` clearly states:

> Modifies an ObservableSource to perform its emissions and notifications on a specified Scheduler, asynchronously with an unbounded buffer with Flowable.bufferSize() "island size".

So why are you surprised that things happen on the main thread?!

And just to be clear about this: your code configures the Observable to *use* the main thread.

Looking further into the related APIs, I am *guessing* you have to call [start()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Scheduler.html#start()) on the your scheduler, like:

```
Scheduler newThreadScheduler = Schedulers.newThread();
newThreadScheduler.start();
Observable.fromIterable(arr)
        .subscribeOn(newThreadScheduler)
        .observeOn(newThreadScheduler)
```

Comment: But I call  `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` too, but nothing called on new Thread?

Comment: code inside of .subscribe(...) will be executed on the trhread of observeOn(...). In your case - on the MainThread.

Comment: i edited my question. Even I use `doOnABC()` to avoid side effect, it still give me same result

Comment: I never start any Schedulers.Thread , at least I don't know is it called or not

Comment: `NewThreadScheduler` extends `Scheduler` where `start` is an empty method.

Comment: `observeOn` affects the execution thread of the subsequent, non-scheduled operators. So if the thread **before** `observeOn` was desired for an operator, what do you do?

Comment: In this case, which operator does Observable.fromIterable() desire for? @akarnokd

Comment: It's in the javadoc: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromIterable(java.lang.Iterable)